# How to direct users to the case they just created using FormBuilder?

Tags: civicase, tokens, formbuilder, links

I’m using FormBuilder to create cases. When the form is submitted, I want the user to find themselves in case they just created. I don’t understand well enough the syntax of internal pages’ links or tokens. What should I put as a Post-Submit Page link, or alternatively, is there a documentation or a resource take me through the syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build a search with searchkit for all cases of this user, create a display for the search result and publish it as second afform form. This new afform has an URL, which you can use as Post-Submit Page link for the first form. Your user can click on the freshly created case then.